# PM2 Digital Ocean Server can't be connected to

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-deployment, digital-ocean, pm2

I have setup a nodejs server on digital ocean with a centos7 droplet using pm2. However, despite having a success message in the pm2 log `API enabled on port 8080`, whenever I tried a very basic api call `http://ipv4_ip_address/` or `http://floating_ip/` which should return a basic `status: ACTIVE` response from the server if it successfully connects.

Instead, I get `Could not get any response` from postman.

Is my port incorrect or something fundamental that I missed.

If I run pm2 list it logs:

```
App name │ id │ mode │ pid   │ status │ restart │ uptime │ cpu  │ mem       │ user │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼──────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────┼──────────┤
│ app_name  │ 0  │ fork │ 33233 │ online │ 14      │ 14m    │ 0.1% │ 23.1 MB   │ user │ disabled │
```

Comment: `http://ipaddress:8080/`

Answer (score 0):

As @tkausl said, :8080 was all I required after the url name.